# iOS app listening to bluetooth connections started from other device

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I am working on an iOS app that will interact with an external bluetooth device. **The device must start** the bluetooth connection with the iOS device and iOS should call my [**perhaps closed**] app to process the request. This should work even if the app was not opened since reboot. Is that possible?
I need it to be in real time, It's not a solution to pull the data from the iOS app periodically, the connection must be started by the external device.

In Android this is very easy using an BroadcastReceiver, the OS receives the bluetooth event of the device trying to start a connection, calls my declared BroadcastReceiver and it starts my app.

Thanks

Comment: Is the device Bluetooth Low Energy or Bluetooth 2/3?  One app can launch another using a URL scheme and the second app can return to the first, also with a URL scheme, but the user experience will be **UGLY** with the apps continually switching on the screen

Comment: The devices is being developed so it could be BLE if needed. I think I don't understand your comment about an app opening other app. How could this resolve my problem? I need iOS opening my app when it receives an incoming bluetooth connection request from a specific device.

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood.  You can use Core Bluetooth background mode to have a pending connection to the device.  Refer to the "lock" example in the Core Bluetooth Programming guide